# Par quel(s) terme(s) désigne-t-on une personne qui respecte toujours sa parole ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Le titre de ma question veut tout dire néanmoins je me permets la répétition.

Par quel(s) terme(s) désigne-t-on une personne qui respecte toujours sa parole ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On peut parler de

> Quelqu'un de parole
>   Un homme de parole
>   Une femme de parole

Sinon, on peut parler de quelqu'un de **fiable**, mais cela se dit plutôt de quelqu'un qui respecte "très souvent" sa parole.

Comment: Je pense qu'on peut etre "fiable" sans pour autant toujours respecter sa parole surtout si tout ne depend pas de soi.

Comment: @user3100115 Oui, c'est la nuance que j'ai apporté en indiquant "souvent" plutôt que "toujours". Je vais remplacer par "très souvent" pour nuancer :)

Comment: (+1) Il me semble que “fiable” est aussi plus courant (“homme de parole” sans être franchement formel est déjà plus soutenu) et plus général (on peut être fiable parce qu'on est à l'heure, ne fait pas d'erreur dans son travail, etc.) sans nécessairement manquer plus souvent à ses promesses qu'un homme de parole.

Comment: fiable = de confiance = à qui l'on peut se fier, qui est très proche de "de parole". Ce n'est pas vraiment une différence de fréquence (toujours ou très souvent), mais plutôt de modalité - c'est plus large -. On peut se fier à quelqu'un qu'on connaît, sans lui avoir rien demandé, ni qu'il ait annoncé un engagement.

Answer (score 5):

À quelqu'un qui respecte toujours sa parole, je peux faire confiance. Je propose donc:

> Digne de confiance

Answer (score 3):

L’expression « *[tenir parole](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/tenir-parole/)* » donne l’idée de « respecter les engagements que l'on a pris » dont on pourrait dire d’une personne qui respecte toujours sa parole :

> C’est un/e homme/femme [d'honneur] **qui tient** [sa] **parole**.

Comment: honneur a trait à l'honorabilité, qui n'a rien à voir avec tenir sa parole.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina I agree, but some (moral relativists?) blur the distinction by claiming that "there IS honor among thieves"!

Answer (score 0):

Quelqu'un de parole

Quelqu'un de confiance

Quelqu'un de fiable (très proche du précédent)

Quelqu'un de sûr

Comment: Quelqu'un d'honnête ?

Comment: @HorsSujet , je ne dirais pas ça, cela n'a pas trait à la parole donnée, mais à d'autres principes, même l'honnêteté intellectuelle. Des personnes très sérieuses et très honnêtes promettent n'importe quoi et ne font pas ce qu'elles disent, ou de manière très aléatoire.

Answer (score 0):

quelqu'un d'intègre : il est ce qu'il dit

Comment: Ce n'est pas la définition que je donnerais pour intègre.